# How can you determine the heat transfer area of a plate heat exchanger

Tags: heat-transfer, heat-exchanger

Given the number of plates and channels (1-number of plates), as well as the width and length of each plate, it is true that the heat transfer area can be calculate by:
A = w*L* number_of_channels
Is this correct?

Comment: wetted areas in contact with both fluids. For more detail see Engineering Heat Transfer by JR Simonson.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the heat transfer area according to a given formula or procedure within a particular heat transfer calculation method.

In some heat exchangers, each fluid can have slightly different actual heat transfer area, but you will use just one depending on the method. Another problem is that the heat transfer area is often enhanced, which is very common for plate heat exchangers (corrugated plates), so it would be greater than just a product of plate width and length, but again, depending on the heat transfer calculation method, this may be taken care of by other means, e.g., using a coefficient.

Comment: Even if you have the exact area, each heat exchanger has a coefficient and they are jealously guarded by heat exchanger manufacturers. I was specifying one and the technician said I was as close as possible to the answer... But he would not give out the coefficients, he was pleased as I had done the bulk of the work so he had an easy job to sort the final heat exchanger specifications.

Comment: @SolarMike I know about this, but still there are some "public domain" methods that can be used (like Kern, Bell-Delaware or FSA for shell&tube HEs). My point is that you should always calculate the heat transfer area as required by the heat transfer calculation method. It does't necessarily have to be a real area of contact between one of the fluids with the heat transfer structure.